# How to address JSON Injection vulnerability caused by use of parse

Tags: json, rest, security, code-injection

I have faced issue where fortify scan report generate JSON Injection vulnerability due to use of parse method of JsonParse.

Report generate JSON Injection vulnerability due to use of parse method with below message.

The data is written to a Json stream

```
JsonObject object = new JsonParser().parse(jsonRequest).getAsJsonObject();
Message<JsonObject> msg = new GenericMessage<JsonObject>(object,hdr);
Message<?> rsp = gwService.process(msg);
```

What could be the best solution/recommendation to remove this vulnerability from fortify scan report.